# How to provide a web view in a class library?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-standard

I have a c# class library targeting .NET Standard 2.0. I want to provide a view in my class library so that someone can use and display in their app.
Here is the simple use case: someone will use the view provided in my class library, and inside the view, it will show a web page of some predefined URL hosted by me.
I am unfamiliar with the variety of desktop application options provided by Windows, I personally use a Windows Forms to consume the class library but as far as I understand, someone can use a UWP app or a WPF app. So I am thinking that this view should be compatible with all these different types of applications...
Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: web view is html page. yea, you can render html page inside of your class library. but you still need a mechanism to bring it into the browser.

Comment: @T.S. I don't want to open an external browser to load the html page, in fact, I want to use a self contained view that is able to render the html page and as the library I should also be able to "listen" and know the interactions in the web view.

Comment: you need to open something as a view. Either a browser or web control in windows forms. I am not sure how it is done in WPF. the bottom line is the same- pick your mechanism of html rendering. But if this is written into DLL, it is still up to what consumes this DLL. if this is windows worms than your code in DLL must be compliant to windows forms.